# Integral of $W_t$ with respect to $dW_t$ by first principles

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

As an example, I am able to integrate $\int_{h=0}^t h dW_h$ from first principles as follows:

$$ \int_{h=0}^t h dW_h = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}h_j(W_{h_{j+1}}-W_{h_j})=\\=  \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}h_jW_{h_{j+1}}-h_jW_{h_j}+(h_{j+1}W_{h_{j+1}}-h_{j+1}W_{h_{j+1}})_{=0}=\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}-W_{h_{j+1}}(h_{j+1}-h_{j})+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}h_{j+1}W_{h_{j+1}}-h_jW_{h_j}=\\=-\int_{h=0}^tW_hdh+tW_t$$

I have tried the same approach for $\int_{h=0}^t W_h dW_h$, but cannot get the correct result:

$$ \int_{h=0}^t W_h dW_h = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}W_{h_j}(W_{h_{j+1}}-W_{h_j})=\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}W_{h_j}W_{h_{j+1}}-W_{h_j}^2 $$

I am pretty much stuck there, and don't know how to proceed to show that the integral is equal to $\frac{1}{2} W_t^2-\frac{1}{2}t$ (obviously, the result follows from Ito's lemma applied to $W_t^2$, but I would like to show it from first principles).

Any tips of hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you take the $L^2$ limit, you'll see it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

For simplification of notation, I write $W_j$ for $W_{h_j}$. Then, using $$(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab,$$
yields,

$$W_j(W_{j+1}-W_j)=\frac{1}{2}(W_{j+1}^2-W_j^2)-\frac{1}{2}(W_{j+1}-W_j)^2.$$

Comment: Thank you so much: I suppose the second term then expands to (with notation $W(t_{j+1})-W(t_j)=W(\delta t)_{j+1}$): $\mathbb{E}\left[-\frac{1}{2}(W_{j+1}-W_j)^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[-\frac{1}{2}(W_{j+1}(\delta t))^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[-\frac{1}{2}(\delta t)Z_{j+1}^2\right]=0.5\delta t$, whilst $Var(-\frac{1}{2}(\delta t)Z_{j+1}^2)\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so that $\lim_{n \to \infty}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}W_{j+1}(\delta t)^2=-\frac{1}{2}\int dt==-\frac{1}{2}t$

Comment: @JanStuller: I don't get your proof. $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}W_{j+1}(\delta t)^2\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }\left<W\right>_t=t$ in probability (where $\left<W\right>_t$ denote the quadratic variation of $W$).

Comment: I tried to show that the expectation of $W_{j+1}(\delta t)^2$ is $\delta t$, whilst its variance tends to zero as $\delta t$ tends to zero (as n tends to infinity): so that the term converges to $\delta t$. So the sum of the squared deltas converges to an integral over the time-domain, as n tends to infinity.

Comment: What I suggest is that you make a rigorous proof, because I don't get what you try to do to prove that $\sum_{i}W_{j+1}(\delta t)^2\to t$.@JanStuller

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I will try a more rigorous approach, but just for my understanding, what is not rigorous about showing: $\lim_{\delta t \to 0}\mathbb{E}[W_{j+1}(\delta t)^2]=dt$, $\lim_{\delta t \to 0}Var(W_{j+1}(\delta t)^2)=0$, $\delta t \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}W_{j+1}(\delta t)^2= \int dt=t$

Comment: @JanStuller: $W_{j+1}(\delta t)$ is a notation for $W_{j+1}-W_j$, so $\lim_{\delta t\to 0}$ doesn't really make sense. Moreover, $\lim_{j\to \infty }\mathbb E[W_{j+1}(\delta _t)^2]=dt$ has no sense. Rigorously speaking, $\lim_{j\to \infty }\mathbb E[(W_{j+1}-W_j)^2]=0$. For the rest it's rather unclear what you do (and rather wrong). Notice that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(W_{j+1}-W_j)^2=t$ a.s. is wrong ! The limit has to be understood in probability sense (or here, limit in $L^2$ works as well). I strongly recommend you to do things rigorously, and not intuitively only :-)

Comment: May I ask you one more question (on notation)? When quadratic variation for a process $X_t$ is denoted $<X_t>$, what exactly does $<X_t,Y_t>$ represent for two stochastic processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$? Thank you so much,

Comment: @JanStuller: $$\left<X_t,Y_t\right>=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i})\tag{1}$$ (for $(t_i)$ a sequence of partition s.t. $\max_i|t_{i+1}-t_i|\to 0$). In $(1)$ the limit has to be understood as the limit in probability.

Comment: Thank you: shouldn't the quadratic variation of $W_t$ then be $<W_t,W_t>$, rather than $<W_t>$?

Comment: @JanStuller: We write $\left<W\right>_t$ for $\left<W,W\right>_t$.